# jibx exceptions

Tags: web-services, jibx

When I run jibx2wsdl on the service interface , the exceptions get renamed to Fault.
for example : InvalidEmployeeException would become InvalidEmployeeFault.

As per the documentation , this is being done to address some Axis Requirement.
There is  org.jibx.ws.wsdl.tools.custom.FaultCustom class using which we can override this behavior. 
But there is no provision to specify the faultCustom properties in the wsdl customisation.

In case if there is any other work around for the problem , please revert.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by modifying the org.jibx.ws.wsdl.tools.custom.FaultCustom.apply() .

We need the same exception class in the service consumer due to some other reasons.